# How to correctly start a sentence with there?

Tags: sentence-construction

> I transferred to a new middle school far away north of S.C. towards western New York. There is where I continued my education through completion of high school and first year of college.

Comment: It's grammatical, but doesn't feel idiomatic to me. I would say _**That** is where..._

Comment: in western NY, not towards.

Answer (score 1):

“There is where” is awkward/redundant. Use either “There” or “That is where”:

- That is where I continued my education.
- There I continued my education.

Similarly with “here”:

- This is where I continued my education.
- Here I continued my education.

Comment: The here and there ones imply the places were just mentioned. But are a bit awkward.